# Converting one string element in an array into multiple elements in the same array

Tags: ruby, arrays, parsing, stripping

I have the following array:

```
info = ["Thursday, July 19, 2012", 
        " \n    4:00 PM to 6:00 PM (CT) \n                  happy hour with company\n                  company100 W. Main St.Suite 5Chicago, IL 60602"]
```

I'm trying to convert info[1] from a single element into multiple elements in the info array. For instance, I'd like to divide info[1] into three elements (hours, event name/description, and address). Any idea how to begin doing this?

Comment: When asking a question on stackoverflow, you should be ready to answer the question: what have you tried? You should try to solve the problem yourself. Google the problem, read language reference, google more, write some code, read a good book, write more code. When you're officially stuck, then we'll be happy to help you. But you have to try first.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I tried for about an hour using methods on Ruby-Doc as well as Google and several stackoverflow questions but couldn't find anything similar. In the future I'll include the steps I already tried (unsuccessfully) in my questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
parts = info[1].split("\n").map(&:strip).reject(&:empty?)
```

If you want to put it back in, you could do something like

```
info[1] = parts
info.flatten!
```